# RESTful web service example in cherrypy

Tags: python, rest, cherrypy

I am trying to write a RESTful web service in python. But while trying out the tutorials given on  [Cherrypy Website](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest) I ended up with an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rest.py", line 35, in <module>
    cherrypy.quickstart(StringGeneratorWebService(), '/', conf)
TypeError: expose_() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Where rest.py is my file which contains the exact same code on the site and under subtitle "Give us a REST".

I am clear that, obviously from error message, I am missing a parameter that should be passed in. But I am not clear where exactly I should amend that code to make it work.

I tried out fixing  something on line number 35, but nothing helped me, and I am stuck! Please help me to clear this or please give some code snippet to make a REST service in cherrypy. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of CherryPy and Python are you using?

Comment: I used python version 2.7 and cherrypy version 3.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CherryPy version that you're using (`3.2.2`) doesn't support the `cherrypy.expose` decorator on classes, that functionality was [added in version 6](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#600).

You can use the old syntax of setting the `exposed` attribute to `True`(it is also compatible with  the newer versions).

The class would end up like:

```
class StringGeneratorWebService(object):
    exposed = True

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        return cherrypy.session['mystring']

    def POST(self, length=8):
        some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string
        return some_string

    def PUT(self, another_string):
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = another_string

    def DELETE(self):
        cherrypy.session.pop('mystring', None)
```