# Cherrypy REST tutorial returns TypeError: _expose() takes exactly 1 argument

Tags: python, rest, cherrypy

Trying to follow tutorial 7 on cherrypy documentation page for creating a REST style API. Copy-pasted code from [tutorial](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest),

```
import random
import string

import cherrypy

@cherrypy.expose
class StringGeneratorWebService(object):

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        return cherrypy.session['mystring']

    def POST(self, length=8):
        some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string
        return some_string

    def PUT(self, another_string):
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = another_string

    def DELETE(self):
        cherrypy.session.pop('mystring', None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type',    'text/plain')],
        }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(StringGeneratorWebService(), '/', conf)
```

but when run am given the error

```
File "H:/researchInstrumentCatalog/dqapi/core/test.py", line 36, in <module>
cherrypy.quickstart(test(), '/', conf)
TypeError: expose_() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I am running cherrypy 3.8, thus [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791878/restful-web-service-example-in-cherrypy) has not been helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question that you linked, I mentioned that it was added that the support to decorate classes with `cherrypy.expose` was added in CherryPy version 6.

You're are using 3.8.

Upgrade CherryPy to any version after 6.0, or just don't use the expose decorated and set a property of `exposed = True`.

```
class StringGeneratorWebService(object):

    # this is the attribute that configured the expose decorator
    exposed = True

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        return cherrypy.session['mystring']

    def POST(self, length=8):
        some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string
        return some_string

    def PUT(self, another_string):
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = another_string

    def DELETE(self):
        cherrypy.session.pop('mystring', None)
```

Comment: i tried adding exposed = True earlier, but didn't remove the expose decorator, so it was the latter that ended up resolving the issue